# Plotting strings vs floats (occurrence of letter codes vs percent composition)

Tags: string, numpy, matplotlib

[image]

I have a dataset of sequences (long strings of one-letter codes, e.g. "ACDEF ....", for which I have computed the mean occurrence of each letter over a couple thousand sequences. I would like to plot the mean percentage composition of each letter, using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

codes = {'CYS': 'C', 'ASP': 'D', 'SER': 'S', 'GLN': 'Q', 'LYS': 'K',
       'ILE': 'I', 'PRO': 'P', 'THR': 'T', 'PHE': 'F', 'ASN': 'N',
       'GLY': 'G', 'HIS': 'H', 'LEU': 'L', 'ARG': 'R', 'TRP': 'W',
       'ALA': 'A', 'VAL':'V', 'GLU': 'E', 'TYR': 'Y', 'MET': 'M'}

res=[] 
freq=[]
for i in codes.values():
    res.append(i)
    # fraction_composition is the function that calculates percentage occurrence
    freq.append(fraction_composition(i))

res=np.array(res)
freq=np.array(freq)
freq*=100 

p1=plt.plot(res,freq,'r^--')
```

The `codes.values()` refers to the fact that each one letter code is actually part of a key-value pair stored in a dictionary, and I am simply calling a function iteratively so that the mean frequency of each letter is computed.

I get the error message:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: C
```

after calling the plot function. Since matplotlib appears to be unable to plot a character array, is there any way can this be resolved? The x-axis should be my list of one-letter codes (values in the *codes* dict) and the y-axis should be their mean percentage.

If I try

```
plt.plot(freq)
```

I get the the plot I need (but the x-axis obviously is labelled numerically). I would like the x-axis to contain the characters C, D, S, ...

Comment: It's very hard for us out here to debug what you have posted because it's not complete or runnable as is - it is good practice and good manners to distill down to a minimum and complete example that reproduces the problem.  However, given the error message, whatever you're *really* doing is passing one of your letters ('C') as a number.  That's as much help as we can be.

Comment: Sorry if this was confusing, I didn't want to put in too much code. I wish I had something runnable to post but I get a ValueError reported back each time. What you say about the error message makes sense as "C" is indeed the first value value of the key-value pair in the dictionary *codes*, but I have tried defining *res* as a character array and the code still fails.

Comment: Okay, I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding ... matplotlib will not plot string data, at all, ever.  If you want your 'A', 'B', etc. on the x axis, you'll have to do something like make them distinct integers (1, 2, .....) and then simply rename the ticks.

Comment: @Spyros you should have at least included the value you assign to `codes` in your code sample.

Comment: @dbliss: Ok sorry, I've included the dictionary as I've defined it in my code

Comment: @Ajean why not post your last comment as an answer?  that'll keep people from coming to this question's page, thinking it's unresolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run your code, I've defined `fraction_composition` as follows:

```
def fraction_composition(i):
    return np.random.rand()
```

When I run your code with this addition, I get the following error:

```
In [5]: run test.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/daniel/Downloads/test.py in <module>()
     23 freq*=100
     24 
---> 25 p1=plt.plot(res,freq,'r^--')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in plot(*args, **kwargs)
   3097         ax.hold(hold)
   3098     try:
-> 3099         ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
   3100         draw_if_interactive()
   3101     finally:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1372 
   1373         for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
-> 1374             self.add_line(line)
   1375             lines.append(line)
   1376 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.pyc in add_line(self, line)
   1502             line.set_clip_path(self.patch)
   1503 
-> 1504         self._update_line_limits(line)
   1505         if not line.get_label():
   1506             line.set_label('_line%d' % len(self.lines))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.pyc in _update_line_limits(self, line)
   1513         Figures out the data limit of the given line, updating self.dataLim.
   1514         """
-> 1515         path = line.get_path()
   1516         if path.vertices.size == 0:
   1517             return

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/lines.pyc in get_path(self)
    872         """
    873         if self._invalidy or self._invalidx:
--> 874             self.recache()
    875         return self._path
    876 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/lines.pyc in recache(self, always)
    573                 x = ma.asarray(xconv, np.float_)
    574             else:
--> 575                 x = np.asarray(xconv, np.float_)
    576             x = x.ravel()
    577         else:

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.pyc in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    458 
    459     """
--> 460     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    461 
    462 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

ValueError: could not convert string to float: C
```

As you can see, the line in which `plot` is called causes the error.

What am I attempting to plot?

```
In [6]: res
Out[6]: 
array(['C', 'D', 'S', 'Q', 'K', 'P', 'T', 'F', 'A', 'H', 'G', 'I', 'E',
       'L', 'R', 'W', 'V', 'N', 'Y', 'M'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Aha, `res` is an array of strings.  `plot` does not support string data.

So what can you do?

One option is to convert the letters in `res` to integers and specify the letters as x-tick labels:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fraction_composition(i):
    return np.random.rand()

codes = {'CYS': 'C', 'ASP': 'D', 'SER': 'S', 'GLN': 'Q', 'LYS': 'K',
       'ILE': 'I', 'PRO': 'P', 'THR': 'T', 'PHE': 'F', 'ASN': 'N',
       'GLY': 'G', 'HIS': 'H', 'LEU': 'L', 'ARG': 'R', 'TRP': 'W',
       'ALA': 'A', 'VAL':'V', 'GLU': 'E', 'TYR': 'Y', 'MET': 'M'}

def letter_to_number(i):
    poss_letters = sorted(codes.values())
    return poss_letters.index(i)

res=[]
res_labels = []
freq=[]
for i in codes.values():
    res_labels.append(i)
    res.append(letter_to_number(i))
    # fraction_composition is the function that calculates percentage occurrence
    freq.append(fraction_composition(i))

res=np.array(res)
freq=np.array(freq)
sort_i = [i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(res_labels), key=lambda x:x[1])]
res_labels = sorted(res_labels)
res = res[sort_i]
freq = freq[sort_i]

freq*=100 

p1=plt.plot(res,freq,'r^--')
plt.xticks(range(len(res_labels)), res_labels)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You had more patience than I, good job.  However, you might confuse the OP because you create a `res_labels` list but don't use it (although I like your use of `ascii_uppercase` in this context).  Also, sorting the results before the plot would make it look less like dropped spaghetti ;)

Comment: good points.  yeah, i'm not sure what order the OP wants the letters in, or whether all letters should be included.  but this gets the OP started.

Comment: @dbliss: Thank for your taking the time to write that out, the letter_to_number function was the trick I was missing. This is bioinformatics data, and because biological sequences are represented as strings we deal extensively with character arrays and strings. Hence my interest in plotting it this way. Because the one-letter codes I am using are part of a 20-letter alphabet (proteins are made from 20 amino acids), the four remaining letters are superfluous. I tried changing the plotting command to *plt.xticks(range(len(res)), string.ascii_uppercase)
* to rectify this. Many thanks again!

Comment: I included an image of the plot on top. Is there any way to remove the unnecessary letters? I thought my change of the plotting command would fix that but it still plots the four ASCII letters without labelling them?

Comment: @Spyros check out my updated answer.  let me know if that doesn't do the job for you.

Comment: @dbliss: Unfortunately it doesn't fix the issue, I'll keep playing with the xticks routine. Thanks ;)

Comment: @Spyros i finally got a few minutes to take care of this.  the updated answer isn't pretty, but it works.  you might want to make it prettier -- e.g., pass `codes` as a parameter to `letter_to_number`.